# Android programming to bring contacts

Tags: android

Hello Experts am new to the Android world, I want to know the code of how to bring phone contacts in an app on pressing a button with checkboxes to select some contacts.

Please help me.

Thank you,

Mehboob

Answer (score 0):

You want to launch an activity for the Intent `ACTION_PICK` with the target URI of `Contacts.CONTACT_URI`.   Make sure you're using `android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts`, and not the depreciated API `android.provider.Contacts`.

There is a full tutorial on how to do this [here on Android Essentials](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/).

Comment: I want to launch the whole contacts list with checkboxes so that i can select some of them. Its not for specific task (e-mailing) I just want to select them.

Comment: In this case you will probably need to make your own activity with the UI that you want.  You can get a cursor for all the contacts and then populate the list with that.